# laravel auth register insert data into two tables

Tags: laravel, authentication

i have my default registration for auth controller. i want to register also the emp_id created from users table to employee table. once registered.

my RegisterController

```
use App\User;
use App\Employee

public function count_users(){
    $count = User::count();

    return date('y').'-'.sprintf('%04d',$count);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'emp_id' => $this->count_users(),
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    return Employee::create([
        'emp_id' => $this->count_users()
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check following line in your code:

```
return User::create([ .....
```

Above line creates the user and returns the created user. Any code below "return" is not being called.

Please try following code:

```
use App\User;
use App\Employee

public function count_users(){
    $count = User::count();

    return date('y').'-'.sprintf('%04d',$count);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{

    $emp_id = $this->count_users();

    $user = User::create([
        'emp_id' => $emp_id,
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    Employee::create([
        'emp_id' => $emp_id
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```